# FileMaker Server not listening on Port 2399 for ODBC/JDBC

Tags: port, netstat, odbc, jdbc, filemaker

I am trying to create a ODBC connection from an OSX machine to a Filemaker server 10 using a DataDirect SeQuel Link 5.5 JDBC drive. I have ODBC/JDBC enabled on the server and I followed all of the instructions to set up JDBC properly (and the connection worked fine a few weeks ago)  But now  I get a connection refused error.

When I run a netstat -an on the server, it doesn't show that it's listening on port 2399.  There is no firewall on the server that would be blocking port 2399. Thanks in advance to any help.

So far I've tried restarting the server software, and restarting the server machine both to no avail.

Update: [I asked over here too, and posted some additional information.](http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/79233-jdbc-connect-refused-error/)

Comment: What OS is the Filemaker server running on?

Comment: Windows 2003...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server *is* listening. Are you certain that your TCP connections from the client aren't failing?

I'd start by using TELNET from the client to connect to port 2399 on the server computer and verify that you see an ESTABLISHED TCP connection in `netstat` on the server. If you don't then it's probably time to fire up `tcpdump` on the server and see if the client's TCP SYN is ever even getting to the server's network interface.

Comment: What makes you think it's listening?  I didn't see that port when I did netstat -an.

Comment: From client, I can ping the server. But telnet to port 2399 doesn't work:
$ telnet 10.11.31.74 2399
Trying 10.11.31.74...
telnet: connect to address 10.11.31.74: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: @Greg_the_Ant: Here's a case of my completely mis-reading a question, and I apologize. Clearly you state that it's _not_ listening. Yeesh... I'm a moron! I see you got it listening but you're still having problems per your other postings. I've got FileMaker Server 10 running at a couple of Customer sites. I'll jump on one of their boxes and do some sniffing around and drop an edit on here if I come up with anything.

Comment: That would be great.  Let me know if you turn anything up.